# Object Is Null When Trying to Add to ArrayList

Tags: java, object, oop

I am creating a program to store different types of lawnmowers in an ArrayList. There are 4 types of mowers that all inherit from Mower. I am new to oop. Why do I get this error when I try to add a mower to my ArrayList?

[Method to read mower data from a file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhQCX.png)

[Mower class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzs78.png)

[Method to add Mower to arrayList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewDer.png)

[Main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwwxM.png)

[Output with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdHPv.png)

I tried different syntax for initializing LawnTractor but i kept getting the same result.

Comment: The error message tells you the issue is in `MowerWareHouse` class but you didn't provide that. Also, you should post the actual code here, not screenshots which cannot be run/copied/pasted/etc..

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. nobody can run that. Edit the question and post as text as a [mcve].  Take the [tour] and read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, it's a lot easier for people to help if you copy/paste your code instead of sending screenshots.

Anyways, it looks like your `mowers` object in `MowerWareHouse` is null; I'm assuming you never instantiated it.

You need to assign the `mowers` object to a value before you can use it.

```
// constructor for MowerWareHouse
public MowerWareHouse() {
  this.mowers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Again, this is just an assumption, I'd recommend replacing your screenshots with actual code.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question lol. Thank you this was my problem.